# How do I calculate the marginal probability density function of Y?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\displaystyle{{\rm f}\left(x, y\right) = \left\{x\quad \mbox{if}\quad 0< y < {1 \over x}\right\}\ \mbox{and}\ 0}$ otherwise.

I need to calculate the marginal pdf of $Y$.  I know I need to integrate out $x$, but I'm having a hard time seeing what to integrate to.  Please help I've been stuck on this problem for $3$ days !.

Comment: Can you write down the "marginal pdf of $\large Y$" definition ?.

Comment: I have no idea how to write it on here, but the marginal pdf of _Y_ can by found by integrating the joint probability density function from negative infinity to positive infinity, with respect to _X_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Graphical Hint: Try drawing the region you're integrating over. Draw the curve $y = 1/x$ for $0 < x < 1$ and realize that the region you're integrating over will be the region bounded below this curve (in the first quadrant between $0<x<1$).  Now if you are going to integrate out the $x$ variable, fix some positive $y$ value and ask when you enter and exit the region as you travel parallel to the $x$-axis at the height of $y$. If you chose $y$ with $0 < y \leq 1$, the you enter the region at $x=0$ and exit at $x=1$, otherwise, if you chose $y$ with $y > 1$ then you enter the region when $x =0$ and exit when $x=1/y$. Therefore you find your marginal PDF for $Y$ will be calculated as
$$
\begin{cases}
\int_0^1 f(x,y)dx & 0 < y \leq 1 \\
\int_0^{1/y} f(x,y) dx & 1 < y
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: I want to say that you integrate from 0 to _1/y_ but this pdf is supposed to have two different formulas, one when 0< _y_ < 1, and one when _y_ < 1.

Comment: There must be more restrictions on the PDF you gave, since if $R = \{(x,y) : 0 < y < 1/x\}$ is the region you're integrating over, then $\iint_{R} f(x,y) dx\,dy = \infty$ but should be $1$. Are you sure that $R$ is not supposed to have more restrictions?

Comment: @user110033 Perhaps $R = \{(x,y) : 0 < y< 1/x < 1\}$??

Comment: I'm sorry it got left out somehow, 0< _x_ < 1 should be there as well.  (Also note that all < should be ≤, sorry).

Comment: @user110033 see the edits to the solution.

Comment: Hmmm...it makes sense but when I check to verify that the marginal pdf of Y is indeed a pdf, I don't get it's integration to 1.  That still needs to hold right? Regardless if this pdf is marginal?

Comment: Yes it needs to hold, and will in this case. Given those integrals I gave you, you should find that $$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2} & 0 < y \leq 1 \\ \frac{1}{2y^2} & 1 < y \end{cases}$$ Now, with this marginal pdf, $\int_0^{\infty}f_Y(y) dy  = 1$.

Comment: Wow apparently I can't do a simple integration correctly!  I got it now thank you so much for your help! :)